# UseCase with multiple response lists in Clean Architecture

Tags: android, mvvm, repository-pattern, clean-architecture

I am using the *Clean Architecture* principle for my *Android* app.
I have a dashboard screen with two lists, one list with feeds, the other with events.

For this screen, I have a *ViewModel* that will contain the lists.

To provide the data to the *ViewModel*, I have a *UseCase* called *ViewDashboardUseCase*.

The *UseCase* makes use of two repositories, one for the feed entity and the other for the event entity.

Taking this information into account I have a few questions:

- Is this the right approach to use the *UseCase*? Should I create two *UseCases*?
- If I should use one *UseCase*, what is the best way to return the two lists from that *UseCase* and use them in the *ViewModel*.

Comment: In clean architecture each usecase handle one network request so I will suggest you to create two UseCases

Comment: @JaiprakashSoni I don't think each UseCase should handle only ONE network request. Imagine we have UploadFilesViewModel which has UploadFilesUseCase to upload multiples files. From VM side we can invoke `uploadFilesUseCase.upload(files)`, and in UseCase side we run multiple requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I create two *UseCases*?

Yes, you should use a *UseCase* per one *Repository*.

Depending on whether you need the lists to be "fed separately" (one at a time) or "combined" (simultaneously), the *ViewModel* might use either the two *UseCases* or a new *UseCase* combined of the two.

Answer (score 1):

At the 2017 Google Developer Days, Florina commented about separating your screen into what she called "logical units" and then observing these logical units on separate LiveData. 
Basically, you would create two view states (or I believe, use cases, in your code) and then fill each view state with the list. Finally, expose these view state to your view using two LiveData.

Here's a video of the conference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ts-uxYiBEQ8
She starts talking about these around the 8 minute mark.

Comment: Thanks! Very useful video. Will definitely use it as a reference for my app.